# toString seems to cause setTimeout to not always execute function for variable argument of toString

Tags: javascript, settimeout, tostring

This code's purpose is to change the background of a webpage several times in a loop.

The following implementation doesn't utilize .toString() to set the color of background, instead, explicitly and statically stating the color which the background should be changed to.

```
var i=1;
function changeColor() {
    var 
        interval=100, //16.66666666, //60 hertz refresh rate
        loops=10
    ;

    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#000"})}, interval*0);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#111"})}, interval*1);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#222"})}, interval*2);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#333"})}, interval*3);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#444"})}, interval*4);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#555"})}, interval*5);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#666"})}, interval*6);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#777"})}, interval*7);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#888"})}, interval*8);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#999"})}, interval*9);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#AAA"})}, interval*10);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#BBB"})}, interval*11);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#CCC"})}, interval*12);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#DDD"})}, interval*13);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#EEE"})}, interval*14);
    setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#FFF"})}, interval*15);

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (i<loops) {
            i++;
            changeColor();
        } else {
            $("#page").css({"background":"#FFF"});
            i=1;
        }
    },interval*16);
}
```

It seemed very obvious that I should be using a for loop, so I rewrote it as:

```
var i=1;
var color=0x111111;
function changeColor() {
    var 
        interval=100, //16.66666666, //60 hertz refresh rate
        loops=3
    ;
    for (j=0;j<15;j++) {
        setTimeout(function() {$("#page").css({"background":"#"+color.toString(16)})}, interval*j);
        color+=0x111111;
    }
    color=0x111111;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (i<loops) {
            i++;
            changeColor();
        } else {
            $("#page").css({"background":"#FFF"});
            i=1;
        }
    },interval*j);
}
```

However, the background color only changes once using this code.

Comment: That's a very inefficient piece of code.. Use `var $page = $('#page');`, and replace all subsequent occurrences of `$('#page')` with `$page`. As for the problem, use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to create a new local scope in which `color` stays constant.

Comment: It's because you're incrementing `color` inside the loop, but you're not *using* `color` until long after the loop is complete *(because of the `setTimeout`)*, so each timeout function is using the last value of `color`. The `setTimeout` method does not block the loop.

Comment: Oh! Yes, that did it. 

Putting the Timeout on the increment to color made it function as expected. 
setTimeout(function() {color+=0x111111}, interval*j);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by "am not i am" you're setting the background after all the loops have been completed.  The following is the method I like for passing parameters to a setTimeout or setInterval:

```
new (function (color) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.body.style.background = newcolor;
    }, 50);
})(color);
```

Basically it create a local scope that won't be destroyed until after setTimeout is done.

More generally your code could be simplified to something like this:

```
var i = 0;
var color = 0x000000;
function changeColor() {
    color += 0x111111;
    if (color > 0xffffff) {
        if (i >= 3) {
            return;
        }
        color = 0x000000;
        i++;
    }
    document.body.style.background = "#" + color.toString(16);
    setTimeout(changeColor, 100);
}
```

I don't know if that does exactly what you want, but you should be able to tweak it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should fix your problem.

I added an additional function call in the for loop that takes the color as a parameter. This way, every call of that function has its own value of color, which doesn’t change over time.

```
var i=1;
var color=0x111111;
var page=$("#page");
function changeColor() {
    var
        interval=100, //16.66666666, //60 hertz refresh rate
        loops=3
    ;
    for (j=0;j<15;j++) {
      // I added an inner function in the for loop that holds the value of var color
      (function (color) {
        setTimeout(function() {page.css({"background":"#"+color.toString(16)})}, interval*j);
      })(color);
      color += 0x111111;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (i<loops) {
            i++;
            changeColor();
        } else {
            page.css({"background":"#FFF"});
            i=1;
        }
    },interval*j);
}
```

Comment: See my edit; I added an additional function call in the for loop.

Comment: I just missed [Rob W’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568968/tostring-seems-to-cause-settimeout-to-not-always-execute-function-for-variable-a/11569211#comment15304913_11568968) which is pretty much the same solution to the problem, but more elegant, when you already use jQuery.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work! I solved it via "am not i am"'s insight.

Comment: I just tested it in Chrome, IE 9 and Firefox. Definitely works in newer browsers. (I don’t have any older IE ready to hand)

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=1;
var color=0;
function changeColor() {
    var 
        interval = 16.66666, //60 hertz refresh rate
        loops = 40,
        $page = $("#page")
    ;

    for (j=0;j<16;j++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $page.css({"background":"#"+color.toString(16)});
            color+=0x111111 //color increment <i>inside</i> the Timeout (d'oh)
        }, interval*j);
    }

    // Pretty wind-down :3
    for (;j<31;j++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $page.css({"background":"#"+color.toString(16)});
            color-=0x111111
        }, interval*j);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        color=0x111111;
        if (i<loops) {
            i++;
            changeColor();
        } else {
            $page.css({"background":"#FFF"});
            i=1;
        }
    },interval*j);
}
```

Thank you for your helps, notably Rob W for the optimization, and "am not i am" explanation of the problem.